# AngularJS Leaflet Directive $scope.markers is not updating on drag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, directive

I am using AngularJS with the Leaflet Directive.

To pass markers to the directive I am using a service and this works well.

The markers are stored in **$scope.markers** as I expect.

However, when I drag a marker the value of $scope.markers where not updated, 
so I added a watch listener to check, like so:

```
$scope.$watch("markers", function(newValue, oldValue) {
$log.info($scope.markers.m1);
});
```

When I update the markers from the main controller I see them getting updated.
On drag they did not, so I changed the directive to include markerData with the broadcasted event on dragend, however I am suprised I need to change the angular-leaflet-directive  to get desired results.

In the MapController and in the controller that created the markers, I added:

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.dragend',function (e,marker) {
var markerName=marker.markerName
$scope.markers[markerName]=marker.markerData
        });
```

This now works fine but I cant help to think that I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you add the `markers` array to your scope?  According to the example page, you need to extend the scope by calling `angular.extend($scope, {...});`

http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/dragging-markers (in the *javascript angular controller* tab)

Comment: angular.extend($scope, {
                markers: {}
            });
is what i used

Comment: your question solved my problem..
I did not do the extend on the receiving end of the broadcast.
 angular.extend($scope,$scope.markers)
    in my mapController solved the problem, I have now removed the leafletDirectiveMarker.dragend listener since it is no longer needed. thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, when I console.log the marker object,its lat and lng properties stay the same after I've dragged it in a new location - I can only get the new coordinates via the event.target.getLatLng method but shouldn't the Market object get updated as well?